# How to receive all donated intents?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, siri, sirikit

App with few intents.
Creating shortcuts from Siri works fine.


I want to create shortcuts from app: from list of already donated intents.
But I can receive only list of created voice shorcuts.
How to receive list of all donated intents?
We can clear this list with deleteAllSavedUserActivities, but I want to receive it...

Thank you!

Comment: As I investigate this theme: we cant to receive all donated intents. :(

Comment: maybe there's a way to check if specific shortcut was added before or not? Don't you know? I also stumbled into this problem